# BeamRunPythonPipelineOperator is not submitting the dataflow job

Tags: google-cloud-platform, airflow, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, google-cloud-composer

I have written the apache beam python code which reads the data from pubsub and inserts into DB.When I create the template file and submit the dataflow job manually it is working fine but while doing it through composer template file is getting created but dataflow job is not getting submitted.

Cloud composer in Project A and I want to submit the dataflow job in Project B. Thats where I am using the gcp_conn_id in the dag file.

I have created the below mentioned DAG file and tried checking the things in the Airflow UI. I am able to create the template file but dataflow job is not getting submitted. Task is getting the completed with out any error. Please log

```
Running command: /tmp/apache-beam-venvvxk4qxz7/bin/python /home/airflow/gcs/data/SessPubSubDataFlow.py --runner=DataflowRunner --job_name=start-python-jobdf1-84a0645c --project=abc-temp --region=us-east4 --labels=airflow-version=v2-2-5-composer --template_location=gs://abc-tempstreamsdataflow/Redislookup.txt --temp_location="gs://abc-tempstreamsdataflow/Redislookup.txt"    
[2022-11-08, 09:44:02 UTC] {beam.py:131} INFO - Start waiting for Apache Beam process to complete.
[2022-11-08, 09:44:12 UTC] {beam.py:127} INFO - Hello World
[2022-11-08, 09:44:18 UTC] {beam.py:127} WARNING - WARNING:root:Make sure that locally built Python SDK docker image has Python 3.8 interpreter.
[2022-11-08, 09:44:18 UTC] {beam.py:150} INFO - Process exited with return code: 0
[2022-11-08, 09:44:19 UTC] {dataflow.py:425} INFO - Start waiting for done.
[2022-11-08, 09:44:19 UTC] {dataflow.py:390} INFO - Google Cloud DataFlow job not available yet..
[2022-11-08, 09:44:19 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1279} INFO - Marking task as SUCCESS. dag_id=DataFlowPythonJob, task_id=start-python-jobdf1, execution_date=20221108T094330, start_date=20221108T094333, end_date=20221108T094419
[2022-11-08, 09:44:20 UTC] {local_task_job.py:154} INFO - Task exited with return code 0
[2022-11-08, 09:44:20 UTC] {local_task_job.py:264} INFO - 0 downstream tasks scheduled from follow-on schedule check
```

```
import datetime
from airflow import models
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago
from airflow.providers.apache.beam.operators.beam import BeamRunPythonPipelineOperator

default_args = {"start_date": days_ago(1),
    'retries':0,
    'project':'abc-temp'
}

with models.DAG(
    dag_id="DataFlowPythonJob",
    start_date=days_ago(1),
    default_args=default_args,
    schedule_interval="@once"
) as dag:start_python_job = BeamRunPythonPipelineOperator(task_id="start-python-jobdf1",   runner="DataflowRunner",                                py_file="/home/airflow/gcs/data/SessPubSubDataFlow.py",py_options=[],pipeline_options={'template_location':"gs://abc-tempstreamsdataflow/Redislookup.txt",             'temp_location':"gs://abc-tempstreamsdataflow/",'project':"abc-temp"},py_requirements=['apache-beam[gcp]==2.37.0',py_interpreter='python3',py_system_site_packages=False,dataflow_config={'location': 'us-east4','project_id':'abc-temp','gcp_conn_id':'0-    app',"wait_until_finished": False,'job_name':'{{task.task_id}}'},)
```

```
Is there any other operator Do I need to use to submit the data flow job.


How to submit the dataflow job from composer.
```

Comment: You DAG appears in the `Airflow` UI ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a `Dataflow` streaming job, the DAG will instantiate the `Dataflow` job but you have to trigger the DAG in order to run the `Dataflow` job once.

You used the correct and up-to-date operator to create and launch a `Dataflow` job with `Beam/Dataflow` `Python`.

To execute a `Dataflow` [template](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-google/stable/operators/cloud/dataflow.html) with `Airflow`, you have to use the following operator :

```
start_template_job = DataflowTemplatedJobStartOperator(
    task_id="start-template-job",
    template='gs://dataflow-templates/latest/Word_Count',
    parameters={'inputFile': "gs://dataflow-samples/shakespeare/kinglear.txt", 'output': GCS_OUTPUT},
    location='europe-west3',
)
```

Comment: I can see the DAG name in the airflow UI. DAG also triggered and I triggered manually also.  DAG is getting executed and template file getting created but dataflow job is not getting submitted.

Comment: In your DAG, you see your `Beam/Dataflow` task as expected ? you can check the rendered tab of a task.

Comment: Yes I can see the task name as mentioned in the DAG file start-python-jobdf1. In the logs I can see below statement too. INFO - Marking task as SUCCESS. dag_id=DataFlowPythonJob, task_id=start-python-jobdf1,.   In short it is creating template file but not submitting the dataflow job.

Comment: Ok thanks, normally you can also see the `Python` command line executed by the operator in the `log` tab of your task, may you check it please ?

Comment: Yes I can see the python command which creates the template file "    /tmp/apache-beam-venvvxk4qxz7/bin/python /home/airflow/gcs/data/SessPubSubDataFlow.py --runner=DataflowRunner --job_name=start-python-jobdf1-84a0645c --project=abc-temp --region=us-east4 --labels=airflow-version=v2-2-5-composer --template_location=gs://abc-tempstreamsdataflow/Redislookup.txt --temp_location="gs://abc-tempstreamsdataflow/Redislookup.txt"       . I can see the template file also in the gcs location.  but i dont see any dataflow command in the logs.

Comment: This command is a `Dataflow` command because you have `--runner=DataflowRunner` but I don't see the `python` command. How you launch this template with an usual `Python` command ?

Comment: I am using the dataflow custom templates concept. In general first I will create the template and then I will submit the dataflow job.    So 2 steps involved in this

Comment: I updated my answer to indicate what operator must be used for `Dataflow` templates, can you try with this operator ?

Comment: step 1: Creating the template file.  python /home/airflow/gcs/data/SessPubSubDataFlow.py --runner=DataflowRunner --job_name=start-python-jobdf1-84a.  --template_location=gs://abc-tempstreamsdataflow/Redislookup.txt --temp_location="gs://abc-tempstreamsdataflow/Redislookup.txt".   Step 2 is submit the dataflow job based on the template file  **
gcloud dataflow jobs run redispythonGCEVm --gcs-location=gs://abc-tempstreamsdataflow/Redislookup.txt    --disable-public-ips  --staging-location=gs://abc-tempstreamsdataflow/DataFlow/pubsub-nocompression/Staging --enable-streaming-engine **.

Comment: I saw your updated answer. That is for the classic templates which were available as a part of dataflow service. Where as i am working on the custom templates. So I need to create the template file and I need to submit the job.